# DI container can't resolve FMX controls

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, spring4d

I have following project:

MyForm unit(just empty form):

```
unit uMyForm;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs;

type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  end;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

App Unit:

```
unit App;

interface

uses
    uMyForm,
    Spring.Container;

type
    TApp = class
    private
        _myForm: TMyForm;
    public
        [Inject]
        constructor Create(myForm: TMyForm);
    end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils;

{ TApp }

constructor TApp.Create(myForm: TMyForm);
begin
    _myForm := myForm;
end;

end.
```

And build code:

```
procedure BuildProject;
begin
    GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TApp>;
    GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TMyForm>;
    GlobalContainer.Build;

    _app := GlobalContainer.Resolve<TApp>;
end;
```

Run BuildProject() causes Error: "Cannot resolve type: TMyForm". I was testing same configuration on VCL platform and there everything is ok. Do you have any idea what is wrong here?

Edit1: I had to change problem description because I was wrong thinking that the problem occurs on both(VCL and FMX) platforms. @RudyVelthuis 's comment showed me that problem is only on FMX platform.

Comment: It rather looks as if the VCL component looks for a .dfm file and since you don't have one, it fails to initialize.

Comment: What do you think `myform := myform` does?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis you're right! I'm going to edit my problem a little now.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Self.myForm := myForm

Comment: @aQuu: if you mean `Self.myform := myform` then you should write it that way too. Now you are assigning the parameter to itself. I personally would call the private field `FMyForm`, to avoid confusion.

Comment: That's what the code should do.

Comment: You both are totally right.It's a mistake by haste. I edited problem a little after yours suggestions. Take a look plz.

Comment: A prefix of `_` is typically used for global variables, not private members. Private members are usually prefixed with `F`. As mentioned, `FMyForm`. Technically, `_` would still work, but it's not a standard naming convention.

Comment: @JerryDodge: What? On the contrary, in many languages private and local variables are prefixed with an underscore. Yes, in Delphi, we use F, by tradition, but not in other languages.

Comment: @Rudy This is a Delphi question, right? Am I missing something? :-)

Comment: @Jerry: Yes, and in Delphi, no one uses underscores, not even for globals (except for low level system-only identifiers, that are not meant for public consumption). Underscores (especially leading or terminating  ones) are ugly. Internals (local variables, private members, etc.) may be ugly, but not publicly accessible items. <g>

Comment: @Yet no one should use underscores for global variables. If you must use them, do it in private. <g>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During registration there are two different kinds of types:

- component type - meaning the underlying type that is being constructed (typically a class)
- service type - a type that can be resolved - this can also be the component type

When using `RegisterType<T>` you only specify the component type.

If you do not explicitly specify a service type for the component type the container will make a best guess.

During the `Build` it inspects the component type for any interfaces and registers those as service types (the only exception being `IComponentReference` implemented by `TComponent`). If it does not find any it will register the class type itself as service type.

That usually works with VCL (because of the exclusion of `IComponentReference`) but not FMX because there all the classes implement many different interfaces.

Using the `RegisterType` overload with two generic parameters (the first one is the service type, second the component type) or adding one or more `Implements` calls will explicitly register one or more service type(s) for the component type.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little confused, but when I changed:

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TMyForm>;
```

to

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TMyForm, TMyForm>;
```

it worked.